# What is SHELL-FORMAT in envsubst?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

When I stumbled upon `envsubst` I wanted to use it for replacing only specific variables and suspected that the SHELL-FORMAT parameter might be what is wanted but I cannot get it to work.

Unfortunately, the `man` and `info` pages don't give any usage example and only say

> If a SHELL-FORMAT is given, only those environment variables that are referenced in SHELL-FORMAT are substituted

Which does not tell me how to reference them.

Comment: Upvoted as a proxy-vote nominating `envsubst` as worst man-page ever.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As indicated by the text, you just have to reference (e.g. by `$VARNAME` or `${VARNAME}`) the variables as in a usual shell command. However, you have to make sure that the shell does not expand them beforehand.

Here are some examples to illustrate this (assuming `export FOO=BAR`):

```
$ echo '$FOO$FOO2' | envsubst
BAR
```

As you can see, $FOO2 has been replaced by "" as it was not defined. Now we can restrict that replacement to only $FOO by:

```
$ echo '$FOO$FOO2' | envsubst '$FOO'
BAR$FOO2
```

using `""` instead of `''` would lead to substitution before it is wanted:

```
echo '$FOO$FOO2' | envsubst "$FOO"
$FOO$FOO2
```

(This amounts to the effective call `envsubst "BAR"` which detects no variables so none are replaced.)

As the `man`-page said, all variables that are referenced in `SHELL-FORMAT` are replaced, so we can even do this:

```
echo '$FOO$FOO2$FOO3' | envsubst '$FOO some more text ${FOO3}'
BAR$FOO2
```

As you can see, the `SHELL-FORMAT` is quite flexible.

Finally, the parameter `--variables` allows you to evaluate which variables are selected for substitution by the `SHELL-FORMAT`:

```
envsubst --variables '$FOO some more text ${FOO3}'
FOO
FOO3
```

In the premature substitution example from above this would have shown the error:

```
$ envsubst --variables "$FOO"
(empty string returned)
```

As stated in the `man`-page, `envsubst` does not process any stdinput when `--variables` is present.

Comment: At this point, I still don't understand when/why anyone would ever want to use the `envsubst --variables '$FOO blah'` command. This illustrates how a technically accurate/precise man-page can be almost useless if it lacks examples or explanation.

Answer (score 21):

Here are some examples that helped me understand how to use it properly. It was surprising to me that envsubst only replaces variables mentioned in the parameter.

```
export FOO_X="value_x"
export FOO_Y="value_y"
export FOO_Z="value_z"


$ echo 'x=$FOO_X y=$FOO_Y z=${FOO_Z}' | envsubst
x=value_x y=value_y z=value_z

$  echo 'x=$FOO_X y=$FOO_Y z=${FOO_Z}' | envsubst '$FOO_X'
x=value_x y=$FOO_Y z=${FOO_Z}

$ echo 'x=$FOO_X y=$FOO_Y z=${FOO_Z}' | envsubst '$FOO_X $FOO_Z'
x=value_x y=$FOO_Y z=value_z

$ echo 'x=${FOO_X} y=${FOO_Y} z=${FOO_Z}' | envsubst '$FOO_Z ${FOO_Y}'
x=${FOO_X} y=value_y z=value_z
```

`$VAR` and `${VAR}` both seem to work btw. Order does not matter.

*I did not understand what SHELL-FORMAT meant either, still don't know why it is named like that. But after the above experiments I think I know what it does.*

Comment: This help me a lot after read those example, from man help and info, only know SHELL-FORMAT exist, but don't know how to declare it!

Answer (score 3):

The verbiage is a bit confusion. To reword the help text more meticulously:

> `SHELL-FORMAT` is an optional text command line argument containing references to environment variables. To reference an environment variable in the text, prefix the variable name with a `$`. For example: `Hello $FOO World $BAR` references environment variables `FOO` and `BAR`. The rest of the string is ignored. If the `SHELL-FORMAT` command line argument is present, then when variable substitution occurs on text received through stdin, it will be limited to variables referenced in the `SHELL-FORMAT` command line argument.

So to answer your question explicitly: Prefix the variable name with `$`.

Answer (score -1):

I found it paritcularly useful for this...

```
    cat myfile|envsubst '$(env|grep AJN)'
```

This substitutes all the variables which are currently defined in my environment (env), and which contain AJN (My initials.), but leaves all the rest of the variables alone.

Comment: This is useless since most variable names in env are not prefaced by `$`, and so envsubst will ignore all of them.

Comment: @user1220323 You're onto something, but the syntax needs to be fixed. This should work: `cat myfile | envsubst "\$$(env | grep AJN | cut -d = -f 1 | awk 1 ORS=' $')"` or `cat myfile | envsubst "$(env | grep AJN | cut -d = -f 1 | sed 's/^/$/' | tr '\n' ' ')"`